# Return value by column name in google sheets from another sheet

Tags: arrays, filter, sum, google-sheets-formula, sequence

I need to sum-up values from another sheet in Google sheets. Column name is called Rating in sheet two named Results!

Tried this, however for some of the rows when I drag the formula down it produces errors, even though the data is identical.

Is there a way I could also link the name in the formula, name look-up value is in sheet1 called Calculator, in row A4 in sheet two it's the name is found in row A2, name format Alise Ryan.

```
=Results!K2+Results!P2+Results!U2+Results!U2+Results!AE2++Results!AJ2++Results!AO2+Results!AW2++Results!BA2++Results!BF2++Results!BK2++Results!BP2++Results!BU2++Results!BZ2++Results!BZ2
```

Comment: share a copy/sample of your sheet with example of desired result

Comment: The count of Rating starts from collumn G2 in sheet2 the rating is found in cell k5, the rating figure can be found in this sheet if we increment cells by 5 each time. I need for it to sum up the rating value in sheet 1 collumn B4, from sheet2. Expected output would be 50. There can be a max of 15 ratings.

Comment: recreate it please here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tN5FzVJBtLel6oJhrVzT4qr4VkWvcGISxgkhPNT97VM/edit#gid=0

Comment: Recreated with current formula, it's not the best solution as it produces errors on some rows in a larger data set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(IF(Survey!A2:A1000="",,{Survey!A2:A1000, 
 MMULT(FILTER(Survey!A2:1000, Survey!A1:1="Rating")*1, 
 SEQUENCE(COUNTIF(Survey!A1:1, "Rating"), 1, 1, 0))}))
```

[image]

Comment: The formula is producing the name, not the rating score.

Comment: it produces both, names and sum of rating score. see: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1tN5FzVJBtLel6oJhrVzT4qr4VkWvcGISxgkhPNT97VM/edit#gid=0